Insurance company asking me to pay more than car is worth for repairs
My car is in the garage after I smashed the valance. When they took the it off to replace it, they cannot now fix it back on because the area it was fixed to has rusted and there is nothing to fix it on to. The insurance company say I have to pay for 2 new wings, painting and labour so the valance can be fixed back on. That is going to cost me about £2000 and the car is only worth £2500. So with the excess, I am going to end up out of pocket to the value of the car. They say they cannot put the car back how it was before now either so I have no choice to pay out or just walk away and forget it. Are there any other options? I know 'betterment' comes into play here, but surely they can't just give me back the car without the valance on it. It is worthless without it as it would look very odd. It needs to be given back to me in the same state at least. But how if there is nothing to fix it to?

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Does your insurance cover rust damage?
